# C# move function

Tags: c#

I want to move file , and rename it , the problem is that I don't know its extension and its original name , I select using openfile dialoge

any suggestion to solve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
int start = this.openFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1;
string newLoc = @"C:\NewFileName." + 
    this.openFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(start,3); //<-- gets the file extension
File.Move(this.openFileDialog1.FileName, newLoc);
```

Comment: You should really use the methods to handle extensions in the Path class. They will *just work*. This will fail if the file has no extension. Or an extension with more or less than 3 characters (like .cs or .html)

Comment: I always use that adverb when the end result is program termination, in this case because of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. But since there are other less dramatic results, I removed it.

Comment: You are right, of course. However, this was the first solution to the problem that popped in my mind. :-)

Comment: @Martinho, if we keep simultaneously editing our comments, none of them will make sense. :D

Answer (score 2):

use [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx).

The [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) property of the OpenFile dialog should give you the path/name of the file the user selected.

Comment: yes but file.move need an destination ,I know the directory of destination and the new name but I don't know the extension

Comment: You can use Path.GetFileExtension (or something like that, don't remember the exact function-name, check with intellisence) to get the file-extension given a filename. And you got the file-name from the FileName property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Path.ChangeExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx) and [`Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx):

```
string oldFileName = /*...*/;
string newFileName = /*...*/;
string extension = Path.GetExtension(oldFileName);
string newFileNameWithExtension = Path.ChangeExtension(newFileName, extension);
```